# How do I diagonally divide two matrices

Tags: python

I've got the matrices like this one. The goal is to divide matrices diagonally in the same row, for example:

```
[[a, b, c,
  d, e, f,
  g, h, j]]

a // e
b // f
d // h
e // j
```

etc the thing goes hard anyway but when we got multiple 2d array which looks like this one;

```
[[6.27639122 1.88933284 6.93039169 7.65928028 7.61386427 7.02603968
  3.69366778 7.8033006  5.23386149]
 [8.19309916 2.80832288 5.72360238 5.89935057 5.54061339 5.89695315
  4.94410835 4.81040098 2.56623579]
 [9.59575635 1.32350669 2.53038502 9.62156434 8.57220761 4.79317064
  2.33664397 7.36509941 5.83053535]
 [2.71706007 0.48238398 8.57049581 8.27609943 8.477555   9.2787082
  6.05349531 6.18617274 8.05067057]
 [3.67787471 1.40262254 9.09370213 5.16377892 5.03992138 5.62662807
  3.3947859  9.97569785 3.5491219 ]
 [6.0357541  1.04628591 7.51343543 4.52739396 6.8337604  4.80497074
  3.08380305 6.24303875 8.9865801 ]
 [4.9943248  3.12563614 5.4112124  3.36648557 2.66219016 4.86366808
  2.41830796 5.15770567 3.16969838]
 [4.55217416 1.74056859 7.78415796 8.41968344 9.64311248 5.96257814
  7.1716518  7.13257556 2.89686399]
 [6.69562379 0.97243812 7.96685776 7.81667515 7.14349812 3.05536421
  2.61668991 3.74354975 9.8144804 ]]
```

Does someone know some fast algorithm which will solve this problem?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want to do? It is unclear

Comment: @MateoVial I want to divide each element in a row by diagonaly element in a row

Comment: This is a math problem, it has nothing to do with python

Comment: As written, `a` and `e` are in the same row, and same for all the other letters. Did you mean to write `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, j]]`?

Comment: What does "every element in a row" mean ? Every elements of an array belong to a row. And what does "diagonally in the same row" mean? Everything is unclear.

Comment: Are you using NumPy? If you are, please add the tag for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[6,8,9]]
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    for j in range(len(l)-1):
        l[i][j] = l[i][j]/l[i+1][j+1]
```

Comment: the output matrix would have an extra row and collumn, also, stacking fors isn't a good idea, I recomend to use some vectorization tool or indexin with numpy

Answer (score 0):

Follow an example in data frame format to be easy to understand.

If you are working with large data, I suggest keeping it in an array format so don't lose performance. So call **NumPy library** and apply `left_shift()` to get the same results:

```
import pandas as pd

df_y = pd.DataFrame([[6.27639122,1.88933284,6.93039169,7.65928028,7.61386427,7.02603968,
  3.69366778, 7.8033006,  5.23386149],
 [8.19309916, 2.80832288, 5.72360238, 5.89935057, 5.54061339, 5.89695315,
  4.94410835, 4.81040098, 2.56623579],
 [9.59575635, 1.32350669, 2.53038502, 9.62156434, 8.57220761, 4.79317064,
  2.33664397, 7.36509941, 5.83053535]])

df_x = df_y.shift(1)
df_x.iloc[1,:] = df_x.iloc[1,:].shift(1)

df_x/df_y
```

Answer (score 0):

A clever solution would be to note that the numerator is a crop of the original matrix (all rows except last, all columns except last). The denominator is similar but all rows except first, all columns except first.

```
[[a, b, c,
  d, e, f,
  g, h, j]]
```

```
num = [[a,b,
        d,e]]
den = [[e,f,
        h,j]
```

So you could use numpy to crop matrices and perform simple division:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([[6.27639122, 1.88933284, 6.93039169, 7.65928028, 7.61386427, 7.02603968, 3.69366778, 7.8033006, 5.23386149],
              [8.19309916, 2.80832288, 5.72360238, 5.89935057, 5.54061339, 5.89695315, 4.94410835, 4.81040098, 2.56623579],
              [9.59575635, 1.32350669, 2.53038502, 9.62156434, 8.57220761, 4.79317064, 2.33664397, 7.36509941, 5.83053535],
              [2.71706007, 0.48238398, 8.57049581, 8.27609943, 8.477555,  9.2787082, 6.05349531, 6.18617274, 8.05067057],
              [3.67787471, 1.40262254, 9.09370213, 5.16377892, 5.03992138, 5.62662807, 3.3947859, 9.97569785, 3.5491219], 
              [6.0357541, 1.04628591, 7.51343543, 4.52739396, 6.8337604, 4.80497074, 3.08380305, 6.24303875, 8.9865801], 
              [4.9943248, 3.12563614, 5.4112124, 3.36648557, 2.66219016, 4.86366808, 2.41830796, 5.15770567, 3.16969838], 
              [4.55217416, 1.74056859, 7.78415796, 8.41968344, 9.64311248, 5.96257814, 7.1716518, 7.13257556, 2.89686399], 
              [6.69562379, 0.97243812, 7.96685776, 7.81667515, 7.14349812, 3.05536421, 2.61668991, 3.74354975, 9.8144804 ]])

#num = B[:-1,:-1]
#den = B[1:,1:]
res= B[:-1,:-1]/B[1:,1:] #num/den
```